# Simple Javascript Clock Variable Assignment

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment

The following annotated javascript code creates a simple timer, which appears in the console log for the sake of MWE. I am trying to explain every bit of this code, but I'm stuck on the details of the assignment in sections 2 and 10. I humbly request help filling in the missing pieces.

```
//1-Create a function "startTimer" with parameter "duration"
function startTimer(duration) {

//2-Declare a variable "timer" with some strange comma separated assignment (HELP HERE)
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

//3-Declare an unassigned variable "output"
var output;

//4-setInterval, which has the syntax *setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)* indicated that the code below will be performed every interval of 1000 ms, or every one second.
setInterval(function () {

//5-Assign variable "minutes" the value of timer/60 and has radix (base) 10.
minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);

//6-Assign variable "seconds" the value of timer mod 60 and has radix (base) 10.
seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

//7-Assign variable "minutes" to the value of "0" + minutes if minutes < 10, or minutes if not. This is accomplished with the ternary operator "?", which has syntax *condition ? exprT : exprF* 
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

//8-Assign variable "seconds" in the same way minutes are assigned, which adds a leading zero if the value is <10.
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

//9-Assign variable "output" to minutes concatenated with ":" concatenated with seconds
output = minutes + ":" + seconds;

//10-If the value of timer incremented downward by one (HELP ON WHAT THAT MEANS) is less than zero then assign variable "timer" to the value of variable "duration", which will be (HELP ON WHERE DURATION GETS ITS VALUE).
if (--timer < 0) {
timer = duration;
}

//11-Output the formatted timer to the console log
console.log(output);

//12-End the function performed in setInterval. Also set the interval in which the function is repeated to 1000 ms (the second argument in the setInterval function).
}, 1000);

//13-End of function startTimer
}
```

Comment: Nr 2 is a really strange way of writing, `var timer = duration; var minutes = undefined; var seconds = undefined;`

Comment: `incremented downward` === `decremented`

Comment: Nr 10, `if(--timer < 0)` is the same as `timer -= 1; if (timer < 0)`, while `if(timer-- < 0)` is the same as `var tmp = timer; timer -= 1; if (tmp < 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Section 2

```javascript
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
```

This line declares 3 variables: `timer`, `minutes`, and `seconds`.
It also initializes the variable `timer` to the value of `duration`.

#### Section 10

```javascript
if (--timer < 0) {
timer = duration;
}
```

The `--timer` syntax means that the value of timer is decreased by 1 *first* and then its value is read for the `if (timer < 0)` comparison.
The `duration` variable is an argument of the `startTimer` function so its value is assigned outside the scope of this code, by the user of the function.

Comment: to clarify section 10 answer, create var a,b with same values and `console.log(a++)` & `console.log(++b)`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is an updated version with full explanations. This code works fully contained in javascript and without any HTML etc (eg, on code.org app studio).

```
//1-Create a function "startTimer" with parameter "duration"
function startTimer(duration) {

//2-Declare a variable "timer" and assign it the value of the parameter "duration".
var timer = duration;


//3-Declare unassigned variables "output", "minutes", and "seconds".
var output;
var minutes;
var seconds;

//4-setInterval, which has the syntax *setInterval(function, milliseconds, param1, param2, ...)*. With section 12, this code below will be performed every interval of 1000 ms, or every one second.
setInterval(function () {

//5-Assign variable "minutes" the value of timer/60 with radix (base) 10.
minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);

//6-Assign variable "seconds" the value of timer mod 60 with radix (base) 10.
seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

//7-Assign variable "minutes" to the value of "0" + minutes if minutes < 10, or minutes if not. This is accomplished with the ternary operator "?", which has syntax *condition ? exprT : exprF* 
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;

//8-Assign variable "seconds" in the same way minutes are assigned, which adds a leading zero if the value is <10.
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

//9-Assign variable "output" to minutes concatenated with ":" concatenated with seconds
output = minutes + ":" + seconds;

//10-Decrement (lower) the value of timer by one first (since -- is in front), THEN check if that value is <0. If so, assign variable "timer" to the value of variable "duration", which was initially set by a parameter at the beginning of the setTimer function. This causes the timer to loop back to the initial duration once the timer passes zero. You could put different code here if you want a different result after the timer reaches zero.
if (--timer < 0) {
timer = duration;
//if you want to stop the function entirely when the function passes zero, uncomment the next line to end the function by returning nothing.
//return;
}

//11-Output the formatted timer to the console log. You could also use something like, "setText("id",output);" to set a UI element to the value of the timer.
console.log(output);

//12-End the function performed in setInterval. Also set the interval in which the function is repeated to 1000 ms (the second argument in the setInterval function).
}, 1000);

//13-End of function startTimer
}

//14-Start the timer by calling function "startTimer" with a 30 second duration
startTimer(30);
```